# document.getElementbyId vs. shorthand (Id.someMethod)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any advantage to writing out `document.getElementById`  when you can just use the shorthand `Id.something`? I'm interested because I see some code online in my tutorials declaring variable `x` equals to  `document.getElementById`, and then them using that variable, instead of just using the shorthand:

Example:

```
<code>
    var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("time");
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = message;
</code>

VS.

<code>
    time.innerHTML = message;
</code>
```

Comment: You should never do `Id.something`. This is dangerous and confusing. What if someone defined the `window.time` property? [Uh oh now your entire code breaks.](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6yz8j7dx/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15768009/2300466 check this for more reasons on why `id.someMethod` is bad.

Comment: You said in a comment below that writing `document.getElementById` every time is tedious. Well you can declare a helper function: `function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }` - now you just have to write `$("time")`, which is still an extra few characters  but nowhere near as many.

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim: That's pretty obsolete. Access to elements via global variables is now standardized. I wouldn't often do it, but some of the old questions on the subject are out of date.

Comment: @squint Yes, I saw the comment on the answer, but the answer is valid regarding the browser support (i.e. old versions of Firefox).

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim: Oh yeah, I totally missed that comment. Wouldn't have bothered you with it had I seen that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you should never use the "shorthand" because it is dangerous and confusing.

It is dangerous because someone else can defined the `window.time` property before your code gets executed, and now your entire code breaks:

```
// some one put this in the global scope
var time = new Date();

// your code
time.innerHTML = message; // nope!
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6yz8j7dx/

It isn't even about subjective choices. It's that you should almost never do `time.something`.

---

Bonus example on why it is confusing:

```
<div id="history"></div>

history.textContent = "Will it work?";
```

Guess what will happen?

Comment: Thank you. It is a little bit tedious writing on GetElementById everytime I want to use it, but I will do it as it does make sense as it is probably "best practice" and will avoid the situation as you described earlier.

Comment: @rich22 If you find it tedious you can always use `.querySelector` which is much better than `getElementById`, or use jQuery `$("#time)`.

Comment: @rich22: Keep in mind that one could just as easily say that you should "never" run code without knowing how it impacts your global environment and claim that it isn't even about subjective choices. There are many globals that can be wiped out by other scripts if you don't manage your environment carefully.

Comment: @rich22 Before I started using jQuery, I'd have like a wrapper function to help with having to type so many characters that often

Comment: Abdul is right. Using a library just to shorten a function name isn't sensible.

Comment: @rich22 A good text editor or integrated development environment with a reasonably intelligent auto-complete feature can alleviate the pain of needing to type the same thing over again.

Comment: @squint I would say using jQuery gives you far more benefits than shortening function names.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I wouldn't.

Comment: Why is `.querySelector()` "much better" than `.getElementById()`?

Comment: If you are going to use it directly make sure you use some kind of prefix and descriptive names for your ID's <div id="MYSITEHistoryDiv"></div>